# How do I escape the wildcard asterisk character in a Stack Overflow search?

Tags: support, search

For example, how do I search for the search string "select *"?

I didn't find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

It specifies that asterisk is the wildcard character but it does not specify how to escape it.
I have tried the following:

- `"select *"`
- `"select \*"`

... and several other guesses.

Comment: You don't escape wildcards, wildcards escape you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Alas, this is not supported by the Stack Overflow search engine. Even [Google](https://www.google.nl/#safe=off&q=%22select+*%22+site:stackoverflow.com) is no help in this case (barring the trick mentioned by Oriol [below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325587/4751173)) - it seems to interpret `*` as 'any word'. The only working option I know of is the advanced search of [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=SELECT+*&l=&e=&n=&u=stackoverflow.com), which is a tool specifically designed for these kind of queries.

[image]

Comment: Well, not exactly what I was looking for, but it is an acceptable workaround .  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 13):

You can search this using Google:

```
select+asterisk site:stackoverflow.com
```

For example, the results include [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/321299/1529630), which contains `*` but not `asterisk`.

Comment: Your linked question *does* contain the word asterisk -- as part of one of the answers.

Comment: @RossPresser I can't find it using Firefox's search.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong

Comment: Right now, it does contain "asterisk" for me as this question is one of the "hot meta questions" shown on the page!

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul True, but when I posted this answer I checked Google cache and "asterisk" didn't appear because the "hot meta questions" list was older.

Comment: Sure. I was just amused. I should have added an emoticon